Android Emulator cannot build projects on external SSD
Status
Can build in IOS Simulator without any problem.
Cannot build with Android Emulator.
I was able to build by copying the project to another folder on the internal SSD and running it.
Error
. /gradlew clean also shows failed
$cd android
$. /gradlew clean

↓↓

Execution failed for task ':clean'.
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory '/Volumes/1TBSSD/StudioProjects/xxx/build'

When you do a Flutter run
Every time I do a build, I get Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets'. and so on,
I got the following errors:

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
:app:cleanMergeDebugAssets
↓


What went wrong:.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:packageDebugResources'.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Unable to delete file '/Volumes/1TBSSD/StudioProjects/xxx/build/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle/intermediates/ incremental/debug/packageDebugResources'

